# Using a where sub select in a main open query select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use a SQL server table in an open query against an Oracle database using a linked server.

My code is as follows.

```
select * 
INTO #customer
from openquery(
  [Linkedserver],
  'select 
    * 
  from
    customer c
    left join customer_contact cc ON c.main_contact_id = cc.contact_id
    where 
    c.customer_account in (' + (select customer_id from [database].[dbo]. 
    [ChangeCustomers]) +')

  '
   )

SELECT
 *
FROM 
    #customer
```

However the error I am receiving is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure customerchecker, Line 24 [Batch Start Line 7] Incorrect syntax near '+'. Msg 102, Level 15,
> State 1, Procedure customerchecker, Line 24 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The query for `OPENQUERY` *must* be a literal. You'll either need to use dynamic SQL, and inject the list of the customer ids ***safely*** into the statement, though you won't be able to use `SELECT...INTO` then but I'm not sure why you're using it (and if the list is long this could have very poor performance or even cause it the query to fail) or put the `WHERE` outside of the linked query, which could mean the query is slow due to the volume of data needed to be passed from one instance to the other.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu I will look into dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues

- You cannot use `OPENQUERY` with a variable or expression. It *must* be a literal, so you need dynamic SQL.
- You need to aggregate the subquery, otherwise it will expect only one result.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
select * 
INTO #customer
from openquery(
  [Linkedserver],
  ''select 
    * 
  from
    customer c
    left join customer_contact cc ON c.main_contact_id = cc.contact_id
    where 
    c.customer_account in (
        ' + (
            select STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(customer_id, ''''), ''''), ',')
            from [database].[dbo].[ChangeCustomers]
            ) + '
    )
  ''
   );

SELECT
 *
FROM 
    #customer;
';

PRINT @sql; --for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note how the `OPENQUERY` part is double-escaped, because it's dynamic within dynamic.

*I make no comment on the performance on such a query, nor why you decide to dump the data into a temp table only to immediately select it back out (you could have just had a normal `SELECT`).*

Comment: Note, as I alluded to in my comment under the question, that the `SELECT...INTO` is pretty much pointless here. I don't really see the benefit of inserting the data into a table, and selecting it; especially when the table will then be implicitly dropped when it falls out of scope

Comment: Which is precisely what I said at the bottom: I don't think it's a good idea, but perhaps OP did it because of other code that they are not showing. "I make no comment" is a British passive-aggressive way of basically saying: I *do* make comment but it's not directly relevant to the matter at hand

Comment: Yeah, I'm just surprised you didn't just remove the temporary table from the solution completely.

Comment: Thanks, yes will be doing some transformations on the outputted data. @Charlieface the only issue im finding at the minute is in the string_agg it is not putting the values in a ' ' for passing to Oracle which is then failing on identifier. If i try select STRING_AGG(concat(''',customer_id,'''), ',') it fails on 

Msg 189, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
The concat function requires 2 to 254 arguments.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 27
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 29
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".

Comment: OK have modified, I assumed they were integers. `Must declare the scalar variable "@sql"` you are getting because you are running the commands individually instead of as a batch.

Comment: The above code doesnt add the proper amount of quoatation marks - we changed it to

select STRING_AGG(char(39)+char(39)+customer_id+char(39)+char(39), ',')
            from [database].[dbo].[ChangeCustomers]